# Dotnetnuke Website - File location of pages

Tags: dotnetnuke, structure

While adding an HTML module to my dotnetnuke web site, I got an unexpected bug. Do not know how it happened. Instead the module tile was added at the extreme top of the page as body text. Please refer this link - http://indiastockspotter.com/LiveTrades/tabid/151/Default.aspx
At the top of the page above the menu bar the text "Live trades - Futures and Stocks" is added. I can't find a method to delete this. I think by editing the code behind this page, It can be corrected, but no idea where the file is located. Searched many folders but no success.

Comment: Check .ascx Files of modules that you add them in this page

Comment: I have done an ingenious workaround. Imported the page template, manually edited in notepad and uploaded. Now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke doesn't create files for each page; the structure of the site is stored in the database.

There should be a "Manage" button for each module (including the one at the top of your page), which would let you move the module to the correct pane.